# blank rows are being displayed everytime I insert data in my table

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have following codes and it runes successfully and says that data successfully entered but when I check the database table, every time i insert data (Despite of that successful operation) i get one blank row.

**Code:**

```
con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='pass', database='student')
cur = con.cursor()    #get the cursor object

query = "create table if not exists student_info(id char(10) not null, name char(20), address char(20))"

cur.execute(query)
con.commit() 

insert_query = "insert into student_info(id,name,address)  values('%s','%s','%s')"%(id,name,address)
cur.execute(insert_query)
con.commit()
print("Student's information is saved to DB")
```

Comment: what are the values in id. name and address which you want to insert??

Comment: Don't use string formatting when executing queries, use placeholders and a parameter tuple.

Comment: @Barmar using parameter tuple is giving following error- TypeError: can't concat tuple to bytes

Comment: You're doing it wrong. The tuple is given as an argument to `cur.execute()`, not the formatting operator.

Comment: `cur.execute("insert into student_info(id,name,address)  values(%s,%s,%s)", (id,name,address))`

Comment: But I don't think this will solve the problem, which seems to be that you haven't filled in the variables correctly.